# Callback stored in class member, how to invoke?

Tags: php

Consider the following class:

```
class Callbackhandler() {
    private $cb;

    public function __construct(callable $cb) {
        $this->cb = $cb;
    }

    public function callme() {
        return $this->cb();
    }
}
```

Calling it as usual like so:

```
$callback = function() { return "Hello"; };
$handler = new Callbackhandler($callback);
echo $handler->callme();
```

produces a `Call to undefined method` error, because the field `cb` is not a method. How to properly invoke the callback from inside the class without using `call_user_func()`?

Comment: If u don't want to use `call_user_func` u'll need to assign the class member to a local member and invoke that member with `$member();`

Answer (score 2):

You might want to use `__invoke` on `Closure`:

```
public function callme() {
  return $this->cb->__invoke();
} 

// ⇒ Hello%
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I was writing a solution with variables and `call_user_func`, but this...  Cheers.

Comment: I am writing an additional question on SO, just for you my dear friend.

Comment: This really is a new question, so, if you get a moment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26784428/invoke-on-callable-array-or-string

Comment: This only works when the callable is a Closure, not for callbacks like `array($instance, 'methodName')`.

Comment: Yes. Please refer to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26784428/invoke-on-callable-array-or-string/26784934#26784934) for what I could do for those callbacks. Actually `array($instance, 'methodName')` is by no means a callback. It is an array, containing instance and string.