# Is there an array-to-callable function?

Tags: php, dynamic, invocation, method-invocation

## Setting

Within `SomeClass` there is `f2member` taking two integer arguments and producing its sum. The test passes showing that the call actualy works and retrieves the expected result. Which is calling `$g`with two parameters `1` and `1` returning `2`.

**Important: This works only for php 5.4.11 and upwards** [compatibility check](https://3v4l.org/as5Qc)

```
class SomeClass extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{   
    function f2member($a,$b)
    {
        return $a + $b;
    }

    /**
     * @test
     */
    public function test()
    {
        $g = array($this,'f2member');
        $this->assertEquals(2, $g(1,1)); // squiggle line under $g
    }
}
```

## Problem

However, this produces a warning inside phpStorm on every method invocation and a squiggle line under `$g`:

[image: squiggle line warning in phpStorm]

> Function name must be callable - string, Closure or class implementing __invoke, currently array

The origin of the warning is clear to me and now i am looking for ways to avoid these warnings.
A requirement is, that i dont want to change the style of calling the function. Another thing i don't want to do is to deactivate this warning.
I would rather prefer to wrap something around it, which provides the necessary information to the *type system*.

## Attempt

I already encountered several solutions to remove the warnings. One is to define a user defined function, which only documents the required target type.

```
/**
 * @param array $arr
 *
 * @return callable
 */
function callable_for($arr)
{
    return $arr;
}
```

This returns an array, but also explicitly tells the type system what comes out of the `callable_for` function. With this type annotation in place phpStorm now stops complaining about this warning, although it still returns an array.

```
$g = callable_for(array($this,'f2member'));
```

## Question

Isn't there something out of the box like my `callable_for` in php to achieve this? If the answer is no, then
i am looking for the most concise solution we can find.

I already tried looking on SO, [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.funchand.php) and google. Maybe, I just searched for the wrong word combinations, here are just two samples:

- array to callable php
- create callable method handle php

## BigPicture

Just in case suspects arise this is a [X/Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem): I have another function taking a callable as a parameter. With closures it is very natural to define something, which can be invoked later on. However, how do i define a callable for a member or a static method without wrapping it in another delegation Closure? The array notation allows to be used to uniformly pass: closures or static/member method handles to my later function. I am now trying to find a concise solution to this, which comes close to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26784934/3165552).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thus, another advancement could be, to modify `callable_for` to take two arguments and wrap both responsibilities; to create the array and to document the target return type.

```
/**
 * @param mixed $context
 * @param string $method
 *
 * @return callable
 */
function callable_for($context, $method)
{
    return array($context, $method);
}
```

Using this implementation raises the conciseness of `$g`'s declaration to an acceptable level.

```
$g = callable_for($this,'f2member');
```

This function still returns an array, but the type system can use the given information to correctly treat this array for dynamic method invocation.

Comment: this returns an array, not a callable.

Comment: @Pamblam I updated the question to reflect that I know this returns an array, but also added the motivation for this awkward looking setup.

Comment: i deleted my answer, obviously i didn't understand your question, but in reply to your other comment, i would love to see how you can call an array if you would be so kind as to post an example of that..

Comment: @Pamblam Nobody is perfect, just run phpunit on the given phpunit test in the question. The array in this assignment `$g = array($this, 'f2member');` will be turned into something, which can be passed an argument list to, when calling `$g(1,1)` on it, it should evaluate _as expected_. This will then return `2` and let the assertion in the test case pass. Or just hit [this link](https://3v4l.org/as5Qc). However, from the linked answer on the right, i got the information that this style might be discouraged.

Comment: wow, that is super cool thanks for sharing.. i'm sorry for doubting you :p however, if you look at your 3v4l, it shows the same error for php <5.4. looks like the issue is related to the version of PHP you're using.

Comment: I already added the information to the question, to reduce confusion. I already was aware of the compatibility break at that version, but you also made me think of this from a new perspective now. Could it be that my php runtime in phpStorm uses an older version for code validation? I couldn't find a config for it on the quick run i will check if this tomorrow. This might be the cause for the warning. Although i should have received an error, but i definitely get a warning, though.

Answer (score 0):

The question was asked four years ago but after some research I found the Closure::fromCallable method: https://www.php.net/manual/de/closure.fromcallable.php